# Possibilities to collect vimeo analytics data through vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

The previous question about the Analytics API of vimeo was made years ago. Times fly.

Now the analytics platform in vimeo has been updated. How about the API functions for the perspectives of analytic? Can senior users get the data like impressions, views, finished, time and date, etc. through the API protocol?

I am now trying to use R studio to connect the API. Anyone know how? Thx!

Comment: Can you post a link to this previous question? Have you taken a look at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start? Also Vimeo uses a REST API; if you post what you've done to try accessing this API in R, then someone might be able to help you with any issues you're having. For examples of accessing REST APIs in R, you can try https://rpubs.com/plantagenet/481658.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a period of time looking for the solution, I have found out another way through python. We need to install PyVimeo firstly from PyPi, and then the code:

```
import vimeo
v = vimeo.VimeoClient(token = "THE_TOKEN_WITH/WITHOUT_AUTHENTICATION", key = "YOUR_CLIENT_IDENTITY", secret = "CLIENT_SECRET")
```

Make the request to the server for the "/me" endpoint.
`about_me = v.get('/me')`

Make sure we got back a successful response.

```
`assert about_me.status_code == 200`
```

Through this syntax we can look for the general view inside the vimeo account, for instance the account information, how many videos, the other URI for the deeper data inside, e.g.

`about_me.json()`

From the README file inside the PyVimeo package, we can get the most useful syntax for all the availabilities to the Vimeo API.

Comment: This endpoint doesn't have the avg watch time or any analytics you asked about above.